# how can i make the server listen for TCP and UDP?

Tags: python, tcp, udp, twisted

i'm using python twisted and i have two separate servers working, one that recieves TCP, one that receives UDP and they each use

```
reactor.listenTCP(PORT, factory)
reactor.run()
```

and

```
reactor.listenUDP(PORT, BaseThreadedUDPServer())
reactor.run()
```

They both work but now I want to combine them into one server that recieves both TCP and UDP but they both use the variable `reactor`. Isn't the `reactor` twisted's, not my own. If it were my own, I could just change the name for each.

Thank you!

Comment: BaseThreadedUDPServer?  Is threading really a requirement here?  I think it unnecessarily complicates the question.  Also, in the future, it helps to post a full, runnable program instead of just a snippet.  See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a rephrasing of MarkR's answer, which is right, but I thought it might be a bit clearer to spell out exactly how this works:

Instead of what you propose, your program should look like this:

```
reactor.listenTCP(PORT, factory)
reactor.listenUDP(PORT, BaseThreadedUDPServer())
reactor.run()
```

It's helpful to think of `reactor.run()`as meaning "run the entire program, and then exit, I'm done".  You should only run the reactor once per program.  However, before you run it, and while it's running, you may call as many methods as you like to listen for new protocols or call new timed events.

Comment: omg, thank you. this is what i was looking for. I did have that in mind, I just didn't know if you could do it like that and I'm new in twisted, so I don't really understand it very well. thank you for your explanation! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can just call listenTCP and listenUDP at startup, as many times as you like, before reactor.run()

Then your callbacks will get called at the appropriate time for the appropriate protocols, and you can handle them accordingly.